# Como resolver o erro no código VBA para completar a coluna com a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

A Sub que criei passa por vários caminhos e após copiar algumas abas para a planilha, codifiquei para o VBA inserir a partir da coluna AD2 a fórmula `=LIN()` e arrastar até a última linha de informações da planilha.

Primeiramente ele inseri a fórmula na linha "AD2", mas não arrasta a fórmula até a última linha da coluna.

Essa coluna uso como critério, para que a substituição de linhas específicas no decorrer do código.

Eu não sei o que pode estar acontecendo.

Quando depuro o código e faço passo a passo, a coluna é preenchida.

Vocês poderiam me ajudar?

```
BaseSemMO.Range("AD2").FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()"

Range("AD2").AutoFill Range(Range("AD2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 29))

'Range("AD2").AutoFill Range("AD2:AD" & lINHAB5T) 'Primeira tentativa

BaseSemMO.UsedRange.Columns("AD").Calculate
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não sei o que esta ocorrendo anteriormente. No momento da execução a planilha está selecionada?

o código abaixo preenche a formula na coluna AD, mesmo sem a seleção da planilha. A condição da parada do while está verificando se a célula da primeira coluna está vazia, se estiver vazia ele para. Essa condição de parada pode ser alterado por outro critério.

```
i = 2
While BaseSemMO.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" 'verifica se as células da primeira coluna estão vazias
    BaseSemMO.Cells(i, 30).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()" 'escreve a fórmula na coluna AD
    i = i + 1 'muda para linha de baixo
Wend
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A planilha não estava selecionada não.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Deu certo!

Comment: O código aí em cima faz a mesma coisa, independente de qual planilha ele está!

Comment: Outra coisa! Se puder marca como solucionado! Obrigado